# next-auth signOut button click is not accepting a variable but the string itself works

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

**Nav.jsx** component code is below. This is working as intended.

When you click 'Sign Out' button, application redirects to http://localhost:3000.

```
'use client'

import { signOut } from 'next-auth/react'
import Link from 'next/link'

const Nav = () => {
  return (
    <nav>
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => signOut({ callbackUrl: 'http://localhost:3000' })}
        className="outline_btn"
      >
        Sign Out
      </button>
      <Link href="/profile" className="outline_btn">
        Profile
      </Link>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Nav
```

I moved the url http://localhost:3000 to my .env.local file (**.env.local**):

```
AUTH0_SIGNOUT_CALLBACK_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

I have changed the **Nav.jsx** file to below:

```
'use client'

import { signOut } from 'next-auth/react'
import Link from 'next/link'

const signOutUrl = process.env.AUTH0_SIGNOUT_CALLBACK_URL

const Nav = () => {
  return (
    <nav>
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => signOut({ callbackUrl: signOutUrl })}
        className="outline_btn"
      >
        Sign Out
      </button>
      <Link href="/profile" className="outline_btn">
        Profile
      </Link>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Nav
```

Now when I run the application, the Sign Out call back URL does not work.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to prefix env variables with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` to make them available in client components in nextjs 13. I have not used env variable in any client component, so make this change in .env.local file

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH0_SIGNOUT_CALLBACK_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

then in client component

```
const signOutUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH0_SIGNOUT_CALLBACK_URL
```